# Why does the difference in network architecture make a huge difference in name classification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, nlp

I tried to build a RNN by myself following this tutorial https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_classification_tutorial. I built my own version with this following network architecture, which is different from the tutorial.[a stands for input layer, h hidden, o output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yibHW.png). Here's my code:

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
def __init__(self,input_size,hidden_size,output_size,initial_hidden):
    super(RNN, self).__init__()
    self.linear1 = nn.Linear(input_size,hidden_size)
    self.linear2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size,hidden_size,bias=False)
    self.linear3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size,output_size)
    self.prev_hidden = initial_hidden

def forward(self,X):
    input = torch.add(self.linear1(X).view(1,-1),self.linear2(self.prev_hidden.to(device))
    hidden = nn.ReLU()(input)
    self.prev_hidden = hidden.detach()
    output = self.linear3(hidden)
    return output
```

This model stops at loss = 12000 over all samples and doesn't really drop anymore. However, after switching to the model described in the tutorial, which the hidden and input layers share the same weight, the loss drops to 4000 with the same hyper parameter. Here's the code:

```
class RNN(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
    super(RNN, self).__init__()

    self.hidden_size = hidden_size

    self.i2h = nn.Linear(input_size + hidden_size, hidden_size)
    self.i2o = nn.Linear(input_size + hidden_size, output_size)
    self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

def forward(self, input, hidden):
    combined = torch.cat((input, hidden), 1)
    hidden = self.i2h(combined)
    output = self.i2o(combined)
    output = self.softmax(output)
    return output, hidden

def initHidden(self):
    return torch.zeros(1, self.hidden_size)
```

Why does the model architecture in the tutorial outperforms my version so much?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
    self.prev_hidden = hidden.detach()
```

Makes you never backprop through time through your RNN, that looks like pretty non standard idea for training a neural network, and definitely limits its ability to learn.

Other obvious differences is that your implementation does not output probability (it lacks some projection onto a simplex, e.g. a softmax) which is hard to verify how much of an issue it is as the full training code is missing.

Comment: I tried to remove the detach here, but I got a runtime error saying: "Trying to backward through the graph a second time. Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad()". I guess the root cause is self.prev_hidden was cleared from the computation graph when being treated as the input to the next forward call. Thus I detached the hidden layer (not inplace method) so self.prev_hidden can be treated as numerical  value.

Comment: I used CrossEntropyLoss so I do not need the softmax layer in the end. I forgot to delete that line when copying from the tutorial. Thanks for pointing that out!